# 1С. Минусы и плюсы Регистра сведений

Tags: postgresql, 1с, jdbc, битрикс

Знаю, что в 1С для хранения истории используются регистры сведений и регистры накопления. С какими проблемами при их использовании вы сталкивались? Назовите плюсы и минусы.
Я реализую систему хранения истории через связку postgresql+6НФ+jdbc, поэтому для сравнения, хотелось бы узнать как это сделано в 1С

Answer (score 1):

В 1С регистры это не только история, это и хранение дополнительных сведений, возвращающие значения по нескольким заданным параметрам - например, материал, склад, период, единица измерения, автоматически высчитываемые данные на начало и конец периода. Либо какой-то справочник значений, привязанных к определённому объекту учёта.

То есть просто таблицы истории иногда может не хватить, нужно будет добавлять связанные таблицы. Но нет ничего невозможного - думаю, при грамотной архитектуре базы данных работа с историей будет ничуть не хуже приведённого примера работы с регистром накопления в 1С: http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000176.htm

Особых проблем в бытность работы с 1С я не запомнил, отложилась в памяти гибкость работы с регистрами - ты ему параметры, он тебе готовые данные.